# split a string based on parentheses and next characther

Tags: java, string, split

I am having a problem tring to split a sting based on parentheses.
I have a String like this 
Fe(C5H5)2FeO3 and I need to split the sting in to an array so the array reads

Fe

(C5H5)2

FeO3

Im an using this code.

```
String form = "Fe(C5H5)2FeO3";
from.split([()]+);
```

I am having trouble getting the characther after the ")" to split out.
This also has to work for multiple sets of () in the same string.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what results you're trying for? Edit: OK, I see more, but why the 2 with the middle group and not the end? That's not splitting on a parenthesis. Also, have you looked at regex look ahead and look behind?

Comment: Apparently OP wants to parse chemical formulae.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not splitting on parenthesis now.

Comment: Use regular expressions.

Comment: Im trying to break the forumla down but it has to whats in the brackets and the next character if it is a number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

positive look ahead and look behind can do some of this:

```
String formula = "Fe(C5H5)2FeO3";      
String regex = "(?=\\()|(?<=\\)\\d)";
String[] tokens = formula.split(regex );
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(tokens));
```

For more on this, check out the [regular expressions tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Comment: Just when I was writing my comment, well done! :D But I think you can do it with no lookarounds in fact.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple regex to match parts of the sequence instead of splitting on a regex:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.regex.*;
import java.lang.*;

class Main {
    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
            String formula = "Fe(C5H5)2FeO3";
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[^(]+|[(][^)]*[)]\\d+");
            Matcher m = p.matcher(formula);
            while (m.find()) {
                    System.out.println(m.group());
            }
    }
}
```

This program [produces](http://ideone.com/SOkck) the output below:

```
Fe
(C5H5)2
FeO3
```